AWS Lambda returing: Runtime.ImportModuleError (version `GLIBC_2.28' not found)
Lambda Function Details:

I am using AWS Management console to create a lambada,It is simple process (I have not added any VPC or Assigned explicit role to lambda function).

Lambda Function Runtimes:

Runtime: Python 3.8
Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
Architecture: x86_64.

I also have some layer added, Which were created manually.
The Error Message, I received:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Source Code:
import json
import time
import snowflake.connector
import requests
import boto3
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

def get_snowflake_connection():
    # Connection Code


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        conn = get_snowflake_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        query = """
        SQL Query
        """

        cur.execute(query)

        # Fetch all results
        results = cur.fetchall()
        
        print("Cost:", results)

        # # Close the cursor and connection
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        }

I tried changing the runtime versions, Handler configuration and also created new lambda function to check with the issue.
